# Best way to reference root html element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, reference, document-root

Which is the best way (performance-wise) to get the root document node (the `<html>` element) in jQuery? I can think of several methods that may or may not work:

`$("html")`

`$(document.documentElement)`

`$(document)` (?)

`$.root` (?)

`$.document` (?)

Comment: You can easily execute these benchmarks yourself on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$(document.documentElement)` is the fastest, by quite some margin (see tests [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-selector)).

You can get more insight as to why this is the case by looking at the [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) (look at the `init` function, in particular, the part that handles a DOM element, and the part that handles a string).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think these are really that different, but `$("html")` seems the most readable, and therefore logical option.

Comment: You need quotes around `html`, otherwise this will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

According to Addy Osmani, `id` and `element` selectors are the quickest.

http://addyosmani.com/jqprovenperformance/

See slides 21 & 25.

So I say `$("html")`

Agree with @AlienWebguy that you can run your own tests on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com.).

Comment: I haven't profiled it, but I think in this case it will be faster to use `document.documentElement`, rather than a jQuery selector.

Comment: That is a comparison of selectors. If you already have direct access to the element, there's no need to run a selector. Or if you do, it will be slower because of the work it will take to process it, even if it immediately maps to the same direct reference.

Comment: I have now profiled it, and `document.documentElement` is significantly faster: http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-selector

Comment: Good to know @James.  +1 for your answer.